# Why can't I access shared folder on my PC from a another PC that doesn't have a password?

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-sharing

If the PC i'm using doesn't have a password I can't access my shared files. After creating a password I can successfully access shared folders on the computer.

Comment: Please add information about your windows version, is it windows xp,vista, 7, 8 or 10?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 and Windows 8 you have to specifically say you wish to turn off password protected sharing as a security measure.

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Network and Sharing Center
3. Click Change advanced sharing settings
4. Expand Home or Work
5. Click Turn off password protected sharing

More info can be found [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-customize-network-sharing-settings-windows-7).